# invalid literal for int() with base 32: 'MJQXGZJAGMZA====' in python 3.6.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

so im working on a python program that has to convert a user input of a specified base and an input in that base into denary. My problem is, with any input, it throws the error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 32: 'MJQXGZJAGMZA===='
```

my code is :

```
database =open(r'C:\Users\-\OneDrive\Documents\BaseDecoder\PyMAIN\Request.txt','w')
basestr = open(r'C:\Users\-\OneDrive\Documents\Base Decoder\base.txt','r')
inputstr = open(r'C:\Users\-\OneDrive\Documents\Base Decoder\input.txt','r')
currentID = open(r'C:\Users\-\OneDrive\Documents\Base Decoder\PyMAIN\id.txt','r+')

ALLLINESID = currentID.readlines()
ID = int(ALLLINESID[len(ALLLINESID)-1])
currentID.write(str(ID + 1))

database.write(" ")
database.write(str(ID))

realinputstr = inputstr.read().replace('\n', '')
realbasestr = basestr.read().replace('\n', '')
print(realinputstr)
database.write(chr(int(str(realinputstr),int(realbasestr))))

database.close()
basestr.close()
inputstr.close()
currentID.close()
```

EDIT:
In the files -

request.txt is empty

id.txt:

0

1

base.txt:

32

input.txt:

MJQXGZJAGMZA====

Comment: are you sure it's base 32? because `Z` is clearly not in range. Looks like base64 to me.

Comment: `base64.b64decode( "MJQXGZJAGMZA====")` does something.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Z has value 25, according to RFC 4648.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the Base32 data encoding in RFC 4648. You can decode this with the `base64.b32decode` function.

```
In [1]: import base64

In [2]: base64.b32decode('MJQXGZJAGMZA====')
Out[2]: b'base 32'
```

You can see that this is actually a string encoded using base 32.